# Use text data on one sheet to search another and output the data on a third sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, report

I'm trying to pull some data from a sheet using matching data on another sheet. I need a formula to compare the name data on my second sheet to the name column in my second sheet and pull through each line of information that contains the same text in the name column on that line.

Sheet1 is a table with multiple columns.
Sheet2 is a list of names.
Sheet3 is the output sheet.

Sheet1 looks like this but with more columns.

Name |    Ref |      Address |      Date

Joe      123       Green Lane   24.03.2020

Dave     567       Blue Street   20.03.2020

Grace    245       Red Bone      21.03.202

Jerry    875       Yellow Ave    22.03.2020

Sheet2 is just a list of names, some of which are on sheet1.

Name

Joe

Ben

Dave

Yuri

What I'm trying to do is have sheet 3 output each line in the table with a name that matches the name on Sheet2. So with the examples I gave previously my desired outcome would be:

Name |    Ref

Joe      123

Dave     567

(assuming I only want those two pieces of information).

My best guess is that it's some sort of VLOOKUP or INDEX function but I've not used these features in Excel before and I can't find an existing answer close enough to my question that I can repurpose with my limited skills.

The first sheet contains the table with approx 2500 entries. The column I'm wanting to compare with the second sheet is F and it's titled "Name" in the table.

The second sheet contains a simple text list of names in column M. Not formatted as a table.

The third sheet is blank and where I want to output the results.

If it's not possible to only pull through certain bits from the table pulling the whole row would not be a major problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the names in Sheet1's Table1 are unique then you can populate a column of names on Sheet3 with,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!M:M, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$999)/COUNTIF(Table1[Name], Sheet2!M$2:M$999), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Other information columns can be retrieved from Sheet1's Table1 with a simple INDEX/MATCH pair. If you choose which of the table's columns with an additional INDEX/MATCH, the lookup becomes dynamic based on the header text in Sheet3.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(Table1, 0, MATCH(B$1, Table1[#Headers], 0)), MATCH($A2, INDEX(Table1, 0, MATCH($A$1, Table1[#Headers], 0)), 0))
```

[image]